# Minimise function containing dot products to determine coefficients

Tags: pca, python, matrix

I have a function I need to minimise by adjusting the values of b

$$A = A^T \cdot (bE) \cdot (bE)^T$$

What I think I effectively need to do is:

$$ A^T \cdot (bE) \cdot (bE)^T - A = 0$$

and find the optimum values for $b$.

I'm not sure if it makes a difference but dimensions of the variables are:

- $A$ is (16, 5022388)
- $E$ is (16,16)
- $b$ is (16)

Because of the dot products in there I'm not sure how to approach this.

Comment: So you know A and you need to find b? Do you know E?

Comment: Yep, I know everything except b

Comment: Are you sure your dimensions are correct?

Comment: And do you know anything else about A or E? Symmetric? Invertible?